# Protobuf for MATLAB fails to build in Cygwin

Tags: matlab, protocol-buffers

I am trying to build the protobuf compiler for MATLAB using github.com/BraunPhilipp/protobuf-matlab (forked from farsounders code). I followed the instructions at the site and I keep getting this error:

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/protoc.dir/home/kiran/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc.o:main.cc:(.text+0x2f3): undefined reference to farsounder::protobuf::compiler::matlab::MatlabGenerator::MatlabGenerator()' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/protoc.dir/home/kiran/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc.o:main.cc:(.text+0x3dc): undefined reference to farsounder::protobuf::compiler::matlab::MatlabGenerator::~MatlabGenerator()' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/protoc.dir/home/kiran/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc.o:main.cc:(.text+0x57e): undefined reference to `farsounder::protobuf::compiler::matlab::MatlabGenerator::~MatlabGenerator()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any help would be great